# How old (long) is the Age of Five

Tags: trudi-canavan, age-of-five

In Trudi Canavan's the Age of Five, the new age ends with the death of the "many" a large number of Gods and the ascension of The Five. At some point they begin making White, with Juran having been chosen a century ago according to the set up in the early parts of the first book.

Is there any indication of how long there was between the end of the War of the Gods and the choosing of Juran?